# C++ multithreaded issuing system() shell amped command hangs

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, freeze

i have a logging app, that receives data over udp writes fast to a noncompresed file. Then when either some period or file size is triggered we rename the file and issue a system comand that contains:

```
"(gzip file; mv file.gz xxx;) &"
```

I use cloexec everywhere so no leaking should happen. Valgrind has no errors.

The problem is that everything works beautifully, but sometimes it hangs in the

```
  system("(gzip file; mv file.gz xxx;) &")
```

I did a strace on the program and ran it with some data and lookie lookie it hangs in the wait4

I checked the ps command and it was showing a pid that fork created, so process was there but apparently something hanged.

strace below has a normal fork that executed system command ok and the last one has it hanging in wait4. (in between there are udp reads)

Can i please ask an expert to check and see what i am doing wrong!

I buy beer :D

```
stat("5001", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0
open("5001", O_RDONLY)                  = 9
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(9, /* 2 entries */, 3933)      = 32
getdents(9, /* 0 entries */, 3933)      = 0
close(9)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
fork()                                  = 3056
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
wait4(3056, [WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0], 0, NULL) = 3056
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
open("5001_writable", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 9
ioctl(9, TCGETS, 0xbeffe840)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
gettimeofday({1444247518, 979354}, NULL) = 0
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:02,907 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 100549}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:02,907 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:02,998 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 200931}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:02,998 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,107 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 299373}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,107 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,257 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 378612}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,257 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,348 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 456557}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,348 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,476 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 560522}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,476 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,587 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 630370}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:03,587 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:04,087 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 710730}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:04,087 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:04,267 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247519, 779748}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:04,267 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [3])                 = 0
recvfrom(8, "\342\207\221", 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 3
gettimeofday({1444247519, 853032}, NULL) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
stat("5001_writable_tmp", 0xbeffe7e4)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("5001_writable_tmp", 0xbeffe7e4)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rename("5001_writable", "5001_writable_tmp") = 0
stat("5001", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0
open("5001", O_RDONLY)                  = 9
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(9, /* 3 entries */, 3933)      = 48
stat("5001/1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=194, ...}) = 0
getdents(9, /* 0 entries */, 3933)      = 0
close(9)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
fork()                                  = 3061
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
wait4(3061, [WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0], 0, NULL) = 3061
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
open("5001_writable", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 9
ioctl(9, TCGETS, 0xbeffe840)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
gettimeofday({1444247520, 154962}, NULL) = 0
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [122])               = 0
recvfrom(8, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:04,908 MAIN "..., 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 122
gettimeofday({1444247520, 273288}, NULL) = 0
write(9, "\0020\00307.10.2015 19:51:04,908 MAIN "..., 122) = 122
select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {30, 0})     = 1 (in [8], left {30, 0})
ioctl(8, FIONREAD, [3])                 = 0
recvfrom(8, "\342\207\221", 4096, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44384), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 3
gettimeofday({1444247520, 403675}, NULL) = 0
close(9)                                = 0
stat("5001_writable_tmp", 0xbeffe7e4)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("5001_writable_tmp", 0xbeffe7e4)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rename("5001_writable", "5001_writable_tmp") = 0
stat("5001", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0
open("5001", O_RDONLY)                  = 9
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(9, /* 4 entries */, 3933)      = 64
stat("5001/1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=194, ...}) = 0
stat("5001/2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=177, ...}) = 0
getdents(9, /* 0 entries */, 3933)      = 0
close(9)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
fork()                                  = 3066
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
wait4(3066,
```

Comment: Have you several threads in your c++ code ? Unless you really rename all the files to xxx, can you show the real code of the system() invocation ?

Comment: Yes main + 1 thread is running. main one listens to udp and issues system command for gzip and another one uploads backlogs to server.

Comment: Just found out that system(reboot) also hangs sometimes ... This is getting anoying :S